# How to recover all the elements of a registry key? (last write time, type, value, name ...)

Tags: c++, windows, registry, registrykey

I am under Windows in C ++. 
I would like to recover all the properties of the registry key. last write time, value, type... 
I used the methods of the windows API RegOpenEX and RegEnumKeyEx but I can not get them to work.

```
HKEY RegHkey;
Long RC=0;
DWORD a=0;
DWORD TMP=255;
FILETIME filetime;
LPWSTR lpName=nullptr;
LPWSTR lpClass=nullptr;
DWORD cchClasss=0;

RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\",0,KEY_READ,&RegHkey);

while(RC != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
{
  RC=RegEnumKeyEx(RegHkey, a, lpName, &TMP, nullptr, lpClass, &cchClass, &filetime);
   if(RC==ERROR_SUCCESS)
   {
      std::cout<<"type= "<<cchClass<<std::endl;
     //etc...

   }
   a++;
}
```

The problem is that the method does not work. Did I misunderstand the operation?

Comment: _"Does not work"_ isn't a useful problem description.

Comment: You probably need to retrieve the error code and then error message - albeit painfull if you are not familiar with how.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would like to recover the different values ​​of the registry key. last write time, value, type... And I would like to know if what I did is the right method. Or if you have to do something else to recover all these elements? Should we just use these two methods?

Answer (score 1):

You need to carefully look at the return value of the function.

**From documentation:**

> If the function succeeds, the return value is ERROR_SUCCESS.
>
> If the function fails, the **return value is a system error code**. If
>   there are no more subkeys available, the function returns
>   ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS.
>
> If the lpName buffer is too small to receive the name of the key, the
>   function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA.

You can see more about system error codes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes

Comment: I would like to recover the different values ​​of the registry key. last write time, value, type... And I would like to know if what I did is the right method. Or if you have to do something else to recover all these elements? Should we just use these two methods? Because I'm not sure that this is the right method....

Comment: @Tom13000 then you should ask a new question. I tried to help you with your immediate problem (what I would do).